# Are ubuntu-restricted-extras legal in Germany

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

Basically that is the question : are the ubuntu restricted extras legal in Germany? I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with no extras installed jet since I am not sure is that legal here. Tnx

Comment: I am not a lawyer, so this is only a comment not an answer: AFAIK these tools are not included, because their license does not allow the redistribution. If you download them yourself (installing them later), you should be fine. When in doubt, check the websites of the developers for infos about license and usage rights.

Comment: Tnx for the answer. But downloading something illegal is the problem, so how legal they are? It is pretty impossible for me to find the developers of those plugins - can u suggest any links?

Comment: That's the nice thing about the official Ubuntu repositorys. The software you find there should be compliant with the Ubuntu licence policy. See: https://www.ubuntu.com/licensing